# Enable IOS application to Call API periodically in the background

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I am building a simple IOS application in which the user authorizes the HealthKit for the steps data and we call an API to update the steps to our web application, I want to make API calls even the app is in the background mode.

Is this Possible in the IOS ??

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614175-enablebackgrounddeliveryfortype?language=objc

Comment: but it for the background delivery of the health data and I want that data to be pushed to the server through the API Calls @olha

Comment: iOS provide one feature of background app refresh. Using that you can call API in background also.